# soap ui return fault with custom xml payload

Tags: groovy, soapui

I followed a tutorial on the Soap UI web site to create a dynamic mock service using Groovy classes. It works well. But I can't find a way to return a custom soap fault i.e. http code of 500 and an xml payload from a file.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapMessageBuilder

def groovyUtils = new GroovyUtils(context)
def xmlParser = new XmlParser()
def responseContent

def plateNo = requestXmlHolder.getNodeValue("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns:Details/ns:request/ns:PlateNo")

if (plateNo == '1'){
    responseContent = xmlParser.parse(groovyUtils.projectPath + "/responses/1.xml")
}else if (plateNo == '2'){
    // RETURN SOAP FAULT HERE
}

def requestXmlHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.getRequestContent())

context.content = XmlUtil.serialize(responseContent)
```

How can I add into the if statement for the 2nd plate number a error code of 500 and return a custom soap fault from a file?

thanks

Comment: May be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657539/xpath-dispatch-in-soapui-mock-service-mock-operation/34664007#34664007) can help you. Please check.

Comment: That gave me some good info but not really what I was after

Comment: Ok, so do you want to update the question based on that?

Comment: Perhaps I have missed something. Does the link you posted previously show how to set the response code to 500 with a payload using script style mocking?

Comment: I am not sure if 500 code would send the response. Does it?

Comment: In a soap web service when you get a soap fault it is returned with a response code of 500

Answer (score 0):

So the way I got this to work was to create a new response in the mocking service with an error code of 500.

[image]

Within the script I then return the response which has a http status code of 500.